# Pandas read excel error 'list' object has not attribute 'set_names'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining

I am trying to load an excel file, sorry for not being able to upload the file as its a client sensitive data, but the file has no headers and there are just two columns one is some kind of id and another is a message in form of {4::20:askjas:34A:woeij:09:232323dnjds:20:dsjk}

so, not all the columns have values for id, there might be value in one column and then value after 4 rows and like that. Can somebody please help,

i have tried removing header, i have tried dumping it to csv and then again reading it .. now it gives list has no attribute 'equals'.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in your code, not in your data. I understand that the data may be sensitive but we need to see the code.

Comment: Please add your code, and a mock (fake) version of your data that however possesses a similar structure.